# Spacing of Frontmatter Chapters in TOC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am writing an article document, and the first four entries in this TOC are my frontmatter sections. How can I adjust the spacing between them into single spacing just like the spacing in the subsections (those entries that are not boldface) in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Without showing us a minimal compilable document showing how you produced this code (not your actual document, and not the whole document), but something that will replicate the formatting shown in your image) we're completely unable to help you.